# Bad behavior of a function when lapplying in a data table

Tags: r, function, data.table, lapply

I wrote a function which gives me the expected result when I run it on a numeric or a list :

```
library(data.table)

my.fun <- function(X, k=0, chaine="") {
  Y = X - (X %/% 1e8) * (10**8)
  while (floor(Y / (37**k))) {
    k <- k + 1
  }
  vloop <- seq(from = k-1, to=0, by=-1)
  for (i in vloop) {
    fixe <- floor(Y / (37**i))
    if (fixe>9) {
      if (fixe==36) { mon.car <- "" } else { mon.car <- intToUtf8(fixe+55) }
    } else { mon.car <- fixe }
    ext <- fixe*(37**i)
    Y <- Y-ext
    chaine <- stringr::str_c(chaine, mon.car)
  }
  chaine
}

my.fun(543916151)

foo <- list(543916151, 400001449)
lapply(foo, my.fun)
```

But when I want to use it on the columns of a `data.table`, I don't **always** get the expected result :

```
DT1 <- data.table(V1 = c(505926406, 515349272, 543916151),
                 V2 = c(505926406, 400000336, 400001449))

DT2 <- data.table(V1 = c(543916151),
                  V2 = c(400001449))

DT3 <- data.table(V1 = c(543916151, 543916151),
                  V2 = c(400001449, 400000336))

cols <- c("V1", "V2")
newcols <- c("C1", "C2")

DT1[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols]
DT2[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols]
DT3[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols]
```

- DT1 : third row of C1 is incorrect
- DT2 : with just one row in the data.table, it's correct.
- DT3 : with two rows of the same values, "strange" behavior.

The `lapply` returns warnings :
*`the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be ...`*

I think I understand that the issue is due to the if that is not vectorized/vectorizable ? And that would be the reason why the function does not run correctly on columns ?

My knowledge is not deep enough to deal with this issue. So thank you for your help.

**---EDIT---**

Here is the warnings I get :

```
1: In while (floor(Y/(37^k))) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
2: In while (floor(Y/(37^k))) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
3: In while (floor(Y/(37^k))) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
4: In while (floor(Y/(37^k))) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
5: In while (floor(Y/(37^k))) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
6: In if (fixe > 9) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
7: In if (fixe > 9) { ... :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
...
...
```

Comment: the warning is telling you everything -- in fact it's not a problem of lapply at all but your function.

Comment: try running debugonce(my.fun) and executing your code. see ?browser for help learning how to navigate the debugging environment

Comment: Yes, I am well aware that the problem comes from my function, but I can't fix it. debugonce kill my session everytime.

Comment: If you're getting warnings or errors with your code, is there a reason you don't include them in your question? They are occasionally tangential but *usually* quite informative.

Comment: @r2evans No reason, I updated my question with the warnings I get.

Comment: Thanks, that's a clear problem. Know that it's being called as `my.fun(c(505926406, 515349272, 543916151))`, so `while (floor(Y / (37**k)))` is all sorts of confused. R conditionals `while` and `if` **require** that its conditional expression be *exactly* length 1, no shorter, no longer. Think about this: what do you think should happen with `if (c(TRUE,FALSE,T,T,F,T)) do_something()`; should I do something? Is it important that all or just some succeed? That's a fundamental question of logic and control-flow that I suspect only you can address. You need some aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DT1[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols, by = c("V1", "V2")]
DT2[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols, by = c("V1", "V2")]
DT3[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols, by = c("V1", "V2")]
```

Above still goes wrong on cases where both V1 and V2 are equal in multiple rows. You could create id and remove it again after grouping

```
DT4[, id := .I][, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun), .SDcols = cols, by = id][, id := NULL]
```

Comment: Almost. On this DT, still a strange behavior : ```DT4 <- data.table(V1 = c(505926406, 515349272, 543916151, 543916151),
                  V2 = c(505926406, 400000336, 400001449, 400001449))```

Comment: Yes I see it too, seems best to add an id column to use in the by. I updated my answer.

Comment: Still a mystery to me. I had tested ```by = .I``` but it does not work correctly. Your solution seem's fine. I will test it on a large scale and come back

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize `my.fun`, either by re-writing it or by using `Vectorize`:

```
library(data.table)

my.fun <- function(X, k=0, chaine="") {
  Y <- X - (X %/% 1e8) * (10**8)
  while (floor(Y / (37**k))) {
    k <- k + 1L
  }
  vloop <- seq(from = k-1, to=0, by=-1)
  for (i in vloop) {
    fixe <- floor(Y / (37**i))
    if (fixe>9) {
      if (fixe==36) { mon.car <- "" } else { mon.car <- intToUtf8(fixe+55) }
    } else { mon.car <- fixe }
    ext <- fixe*(37**i)
    Y <- Y-ext
    chaine <- stringr::str_c(chaine, mon.car)
  }
  chaine
}

# vectorized version of my.fun
my.fun.vecb <- function(X, k = 0, chaine = character(length(X))) {
  Y <- X %% 1e8
  k <- pmax(ceiling(log(Y, 37)), k) - 1
  k37 <- 37^k
  
  mon.car <- function(fixe, n) {
    chr <- character(n)
    blnGT9 <- fixe > 9
    blnLetter <- blnGT9 & fixe != 36
    chr[blnLetter] <- intToUtf8(fixe[blnLetter] + 55, multiple = TRUE)
    chr[!blnGT9] <- as.character(fixe[!blnGT9])
    return(chr)
  }
  
  blnk <- rep(TRUE, length(X))
  
  while (length(Y)) {
    k37 <- 37^k
    chaine[blnk] <- paste0(chaine[blnk], mon.car(Y %/% k37, length(Y)))
    blnk[blnk] <- k > 0
    k <- k[blnk] - 1
    Y <- Y[blnk] %% k37[blnk]
  }
  
  return(chaine)
}

DT1a <- data.table(V1 = c(505926406, 515349272, 543916151),
                  V2 = c(505926406, 400000336, 400001449))

DT2a <- data.table(V1 = c(543916151),
                  V2 = c(400001449))

DT3a <- data.table(V1 = c(543916151, 543916151),
                  V2 = c(400001449, 400000336))

cols <- c("V1", "V2")
newcols <- c("C1", "C2")

# function to call my.fun element-wise over a data.table
f_loop <- function(dt) {
  dt[, (newcols) := character(0)]
  for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
    for (j in seq_along(cols)){
      dt[i, (newcols[j]) := my.fun(unlist(.SD, use.names = FALSE)), .SDcols = cols[j]]
    }
  }
}

DT1b <- copy(DT1a)[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun.vecb), .SDcols = cols]
DT2b <- copy(DT2a)[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun.vecb), .SDcols = cols]
DT3b <- copy(DT3a)[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun.vecb), .SDcols = cols]

my.fun.vecc <- Vectorize(my.fun) # alternative vectorized version of my.fun
DT1c <- copy(DT1a)[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun.vecc), .SDcols = cols]
DT2c <- copy(DT2a)[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun.vecc), .SDcols = cols]
DT3c <- copy(DT3a)[, (newcols) := lapply(.SD, my.fun.vecc), .SDcols = cols]

f_loop(DT1a)
f_loop(DT2a)
f_loop(DT3a)

# check that the versions of the data.tables are all the same
identical(list(DT1a, DT2a, DT3a), list(DT1b, DT2b, DT3b))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(list(DT1a, DT2a, DT3a), list(DT1c, DT2c, DT3c))
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2021-11-08 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: Woh thanks for your time. I need to study your code and test it on larger data but it seems great !